# What are the benefits of Subscriber key Migration?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

I'm working with a client who is looking to move their CRM to Sales cloud and are looking to subscriber key migration as contacts will be synced through MC connector integration.

- They have been using an email address as Subscriber key in SFMC as their old CRM uses it a unique identifier.
- They have also been extracting all their tracking data from SFMC and building reports externally.
- They are not looking to do segmentation based on engagement data like opens and clicks.

So if they not going to use their SFMC tracking data associated with subscribers what other benefits does Subscriber Key migration offer?

I want to make sure if there are other benefits we should consider, which might affect us if the subscribers were deleted instead of doing a migration.

By subscriber key migration I'm referring to the process of replacing current subscribers with SFDC ContactID/PersonContactID which is done by the salesforce support team and has a 1-week downtime & cost associated with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been in a project that involved a Subscriber Key migration to Sales Cloud format when both key variations existed in the system at the same time, and the reasons why client went through with it are as follows:

- Get rid of duplicate Contacts for the billing purposes.
- Keep all the Send History and Subscription Permissions tied to the same Contacts.
- Get Tracking Data sent back to Sales Cloud for *all* the Marketing Cloud Sends.

Basically, if your client does not care about current Subscription status of the Contacts, the historic trail of messages sent, the Markting Cloud internal reporting numbers for the sends/automations, then there is **no** reason to consisder the migration project.

I would advise to export all the subscriber-related data out of Marketing Cloud, update any of the permissions of subscriptions in Sales Cloud (like setting `EmailOptOut`, which is a standard Sales Cloud field used for Unsubscribes) and simply start from scratch with fresh Contacts utilizing proper ID's.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Rain